# Matrices: help with homework

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I need to prove that $\vec{x}$ is a solution of $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
2&-7&-3\\
-4&1&5\\
1&3&-1\\
\end{vmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{vmatrix}
5\\
-1\\
7\\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
-4\\
14\\
-5\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I've done scalar multiplication and have gotten the right answer:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
2\cdot5+(-7)\cdot(-1)+(-3)\cdot7\\
(-4)\cdot5+1\cdot(-1)+5\cdot7\\
1\cdot5+3\cdot(-1)+(-1)\cdot7\\
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
-4\\
14\\
-5\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
My question is how would I go the other way, with only $A$ and $\vec{b}$ get $\vec{x}$?

Comment: You can use Gaussian elimination for this.

Comment: Multiply both sides by the inverse of A?

Comment: Solve the linear equations.

Comment: Take a look at https://brilliant.org/wiki/gaussian-elimination/

Comment: Three excellent (if somewhat brief) answers. All posted as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reduce the augmented matrix to the Row Reduced Echelon Form (RREF). The RREF will have a row of zeros which means there is a free variable. So the system has infinitely many solutions. You can pick an "appropriate" value of the free variable and show that (5,-1,7) is one of the solutions. This process of solving the system is called Gauss-Jordan elimination.

Since it is a homework question, I cannot give out well-written complete solution. However, you can find many examples on Gauss-Jordan elimination if you google it.